# About Java XML xPath.compile

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have trains.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<trains> 
  <train id="1"> 
       <from>Kyiv</from>  
       <to>Donetsk</to> 
       <date>10.04.2014</date> 
       <depart>14:00</depart> 
  </train> 
  <train id="2"> 
       <from>Odesa</from>  
       <to>Lviv</to> 
       <date>10.04.2014</date> 
       <depart>17:00</depart> 
  </train> 
</trains>
```

And fragment from `Main.java`:

```
String expression = "/trains/train[depart<17:00]";
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

But it will be runtime exception.

If i write `String expression = "/trains/train[departure]/from";` then it runs.
Result:

```
Kyiv

Lviv
```

But I need so result in console that shows just trains which depart before 17-00. How should i do it right in String expression?

Comment: And the details of the exception are...?

Comment: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException

Comment: Well that's the *name* of the exception. Have a look at the message, which will give more explanation as to what's wrong.

Comment: I know what's wrong - phrase "depart<17:00" is wrong but how can i sort this trains which depart before 17-00?

Comment: You've missed the point I was trying to make. When you've got an exception and you're asking for help, you should *always always always* give the details of the exception. Yes, we could probably work out what's wrong ourselves - but it's relevant information that you already have to hand, so you should include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the lines of Ian's answer, if you're only worried about checking the hour you could use substring:

```
//trains/train[number(substring(depart, 1, 2)) < 17]
```

But I would personally go with Ian's to check the entire time.

To fix the issue Ian pointed out:

```
//trains/train[number(substring-before(depart, ':')) < 17]
```

Comment: This works as long as every entry uses two digits for the hour.  If you happen to get a `9:30` instead of `09:30` then it'll break down.

Comment: @IanRoberts Good point, thanks for adding that. As I said, the solution you gave is much better, but I added an edit to account for it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly `17:00` isn't a valid literal on its own in XPath, you need to wrap it in quotes (single or double) if you want to treat it as a string.

```
/trains/train[depart<'17:00']
```

however `<` comparison between strings only works in XPath 2.0.  If you're limited to 1.0 (which you will be unless your application includes Saxon) then the less than operator is only defined between numbers.  So you would need to convert the string to a suitable number to do the comparison by removing the colon

```
/trains/train[number(translate(depart, ':', '')) < 1700]
```